# Wordpress 3.1 - TinyMCE inserts "non-standard" quote marks - how to fix?

Tags: wordpress, unicode, tinymce, ascii, quotes

For some reason, the TinyMCE editor that ships with Wordpress feels a need to display smart quotes *a la* MS Word, instead of text (`ASCII`) quotes.

The smart quotes goof-up some plugin searches, and/or copy/pasting the text into a search box (for example into Amazon).

Is there a way to force TinyMCE to use regular quotes instead of unicode ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Smart quotes are performed by the wptexturize function. You can disable them by removing the filter in your functions.php file.

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
```

Comment: this I did not know! Thanks, Chris_O - going to try this